How can I create a good high probability unique uin64 hashmap key with two bitboards plus one bit that represents players turn?
I have two bitboards that represent two players in the game Connect 4. The bits that are used are bits from 0 to 48, so 49 bits in total. The representation looks like this:
  6 13 20 27 34 41 48   55 62     Additional row
+---------------------+ 
| 5 12 19 26 33 40 47 | 54 61     top row
| 4 11 18 25 32 39 46 | 53 60
| 3 10 17 24 31 38 45 | 52 59
| 2  9 16 23 30 37 44 | 51 58
| 1  8 15 22 29 36 43 | 50 57
| 0  7 14 21 28 35 42 | 49 56 63  bottom row
+---------------------+

The top row is not being used for anything particular, but this setup makes it easier to check for wins. There are 7 columns and 6 rows as in the game of Connect 4.
The bits are structured as follows:
... 0000000 0000000 0000010 0000011 0000000 0000000 0000000 // encoding Xs
... 0000000 0000000 0000001 0000100 0000001 0000000 0000000 // encoding Os
      col 6   col 5   col 4   col 3   col 2   col 1   col 0

So we use 7 bits for each column, we ignore the last bit in each column as there are only 6 rows per column.
I am using hash maps in Go to save states while running minimax with alpha beta pruning. The map is a transposition table to check for previously visited states. A state can be uniquely identified by player X bitboard, player O bitboard, and players turn, which is just a 0 or 1.
Right now I am using a Go struct as key in the map, but I would like to use uint64 as key to make it more efficient.
type TTFlag int64

const (
    Exact      TTFlag = 0
    UpperBound TTFlag = 1
    LowerBound TTFlag = 2
)

type TTKey struct {
    Bitboard   [2]uint64
    PlayerTurn int
}

type TTEntry struct {
    BestScore float64
    BestMove  int
    Flag      TTFlag
    Depth     int
    IsValid   bool
}

type Solver struct {
    NodeVisitCounter int
    TTMapHitCounter  int
    TTMap *swiss.Map[TTKey, TTEntry]
}

func NewSolver() *Solver {
    return &Solver{
        NodeVisitCounter: 0,
        TTMapHitCounter:  0,
        TTMap: swiss.NewMap[TTKey, TTEntry](1 << 25), // 1 << 25 // 33,554,432
    }
}

func (s *Solver) StoreEntry(p *Position, entry TTEntry) {
    ttKey := TTKey{Bitboard: p.Bitboard, PlayerTurn: p.PlayerTurn}
    s.TTMap.Put(ttKey, entry)
}

func (s *Solver) RetrieveEntry(p *Position) TTEntry {
    ttKey := TTKey{Bitboard: p.Bitboard, PlayerTurn: p.PlayerTurn}
    if entry, exists := s.TTMap.Get(ttKey); exists {
        s.TTMapHitCounter++
        return entry
    }
    return TTEntry{}
}

I'm not sure if using the whole struct as a key is the best idea for performance. However, I don't know how to make a high probabilty unique uint64 key from 49 x2 bits + 1 bit (to represent player turn).
There are third party go hash maps like github.com/alphadose/haxmap, that are faster than the built in go map, but they only support primitive keys like uint64.
How I can solve this problem?

For starters, you can pack the turn indicator into one of the bit fields, since not all bits are used. You can use, say, the highest bit of Bitboard[0] instead of the int. That gets the key down to [2]uint64. I doubt that hashing two integers is an actual bottleneck. Have you measured that or is it a guess?

It is just a guess, but I know some third party hash maps are much faster, like haxmap for Go. But they only support primitive values like uint64, I am guessing if I could pack this into a uint64 in a creative way, that could improve the performance since I would be using the faster hash maps. But I don't know how to do it.

Ok I put the player turn in bit 49, if player turn is 0 i do nothing, if player turn is 1, then i set bit 49 in both bitboards, now the key is [2]uint64, is there a good way of hashing this to uint64?
